# Proget server feed does not include Nuget packages even though package has been pushed to the Proget server successfully

Tags: proget

We are using Proget 4.4.2.5. We can successfully push the Nuget package to the Proget server but am not seeing the package in the feed.

The "nuget install" command fails when we omit the version (i.e. we want to fetch only the latest). It works for other Nuget packages that appear in the feed when version is omitted. The nuget install command only works on this package when the version is specified.

I have tried restarting the Proget Service but that does not appear to resolve the issue.

**Thanks in advance for any assistance. This is an ugent / blocking issues for us.**

Answer (score 0):

Figured out that my specific package is a pre-release and thus required the prerelease option to be set on the nuget install command.